# Caption in TPanel like TRadioGroup?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

How can I place the caption of a TPanel over the top line, like the caption of TRadioGroup?

In a form, I want to create several groups of controls. Each group is within a rectangle and I need to put the caption in the top-left of the rectangle, over the line. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a panel, use a [`TGroupBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TGroupBox) which is designed to, well, group controls inside it and paints the caption in the place you want it.

> TGroupBox represents a Windows group box.
>   The TGroupBox component represents a standard Windows group box, used to group related controls on a form. When another control component is placed within a group box, the group box becomes the parent of that component.

[image: GroupBox during runtime]

Answer (score 0):

You can place a TLabel on this panel having the caption of it, or as jachguate mentioend use a TGroupBox.

If you insist to use a panel, how about trying TAdvSmoothPanel, which is a TMS Component.